# Why java returns different types from same method parameters?

Tags: java, types

Why i can't assign normal numbers to a array?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int r = 100 + (int) (Math.random()*999); // create random number from 100 to 999
    int a [] = new int[String.valueOf(r).length()]; // create array with r length
    for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++) {
        a[i] = String.valueOf(r).charAt(i);
        System.out.println(a[i]); // returns numbers from 48 to 57 (dec)
        System.out.println(String.valueOf(r).charAt(i)); // returns numbers from 0 to 9
    }
```

Comment: The first one prints the `Integer` value of the `char` as you store it in an `int`, the second one the `char` itself as you directly acces the overloaded `println`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By "returns" I assume you mean "outputs". `println` doesn't *return* anything.

The outputs are different because you're calling different methods. On this line:

```
System.out.println(a[i]); // returns numbers from 48 to 57 (dec)
```

...you're calling [`System.out.println(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println-int-), which outputs a decimal representation of the numeric value you stored in `a[i]`, which is the numeric value of the character (for instance, 57 for the character `'9'`).

But on this line:

```
System.out.println(String.valueOf(r).charAt(i)); // returns numbers from 0 to 9
```

...you're calling [`System.out.println(char)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println-char-), which outputs the actual character (for instance, `'9'`).

You've said in a comment:

> If r for example will be 789 and i = 2, than that code will return 9, right? Then i assign `a[2] = 9` (`a[i] = String.valueOf(r).charAt(i);`), so when i call `a[2]` it must return `9` - value that stores in third element of a arrray. I dont need decimal value of that number and im not "saying" this to java.

Ah, but you are. :-) `println` is *overloaded* — there are different versions of it based on the *type* of the argument you give it.

When you do:

```
a[i] = String.valueOf(r).charAt(i);
```

you're taking a `char` (the return value of `charAt`) and *promoting* it to an `int` (the type of `a[i]`). The `char` value `'9'` is promoted to the `int` value 57 (the numeric version of that character). Then when you do

```
System.out.println(a[i]);
```

the type of `a[i]` (`int`) is what decides which `println` is called: `println(int)`. `println(int)` outputs the decimal representation of the number you give it: 57.

When you do

```
System.out.println(String.valueOf(r).charAt(i));
```

the type of `String.valueOf(r).charAt(i)` is `char` (the return type of `charAt`), and so you call `println(char)` instead. `println(char)` outputs the *character* you give it, `'9'`.

Comment: Yes, i mean outputs. In `String.valueOf(r).charAt(i);` returns same data. If r for example will be 789 and i = 2, than that code will return 9, right? Then i assign a[2] = 9 (`a[i] = String.valueOf(r).charAt(i);`), so when i call a[2] it must return 9 - value that stores in third element of a arrray. I dont need decimal value of that number and im not "saying" this to java.

Comment: @nikolay: The same data, yes; but with a different type. I've added to the answer to explain.

Comment: Ever cooked? Garlic - same ingredient - but taste is different depending on if being grated or chopped...

Comment: i tried `a[i] = (char) String.valueOf(r).charAt(i);` but it makes no sense, Than i put `System.out.println( (char) a[i])` to output returned a[i] integer value in a character.

Comment: @nikolay: I think there is a fundamental misunderstanding I want to hint to a little more ecplicitly than in the ansewr given: if you convert int 789 to String, you get "789", which basically is a character sequence of {'7', '8', '9'}. Be aware of the single quotes!!! '7' is a character just as is 'b'. Unfortunately, the numerical value of the digit *character* is not equal to the value of the digit itself, but has an offset depending on the underlying charset. In ASCII (and thus unicode, too), '0' is mapped to the numerical value of 48, '1' to 49, ... '9' to 57.

Comment: @Aconcagua  Yes, my problem was that I didt notice that int is not automatically converted to char (wich is **un**logical).

Comment: @nikolay: The `(char)` in `a[i] = (char) String.valueOf(r).charAt(i);` doesn't do anything; the value of `String.valueOf(r).charAt(i)` is *already* a `char`. It's the act of assigning it to `a[i]` that does the promotion. `System.out.println((char)a[i]);` calls `println(char)` because you've changed the type of the argument to `char` from `int`. (Why not just use a `char[]` for `a` in the first place, if you don't want to convert to `int`?)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, I not use `char[]` because its not a full code, so there is more operatons i need to do with integer values of `a[]` (find out what the number of `a[]` is bigger, wich i suppose you cant do with char, but ofc i can be wrong).

Comment: @nikolay: `>`, `<`, etc., all work with `char`. In fact, `char` is an [integral type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.1) like `int`. (That said, you'll find lots of APIs in the JDK that use `int` instead of `char`, usually so they can use -1 as a flag value of some kind [end of input, etc.].)

Answer (score 2):

The array is being filled by the UTF-16 value of the character instead of the actual number. You can use `Character.digit(char c, int radix)` to get the numeric value:

```
a[i] = Character.digit(String.valueOf(r).charAt(i), 10);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are asking different questions in the title and in the body:

> Why java returns different types from same method parameters?

Both calls to `System.out.println` are *accepting* (not returning) different types (`char` in the first call in your code, `int` in the second), because the `println` method is overloaded (for a general discussion of overloading see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_overloading)

> Why I can't assign normal numbers to a array?

You can certainly assign "normal numbers" to an int[] array. However note that this line:

```
a[i] = String.valueOf(r).charAt(i);
```

Is probably not doing what you think: It is not assigning the 'digit' at index `i` in string `r`, but the ASCII (actually Unicode) code for that digit instead.

Comment: The overloaded function must differ either by the arity or data types.

Comment: @nikolay it isn´t, you just store the `int` value of the `char` in the `int[]`, as for `char->int` conversion. For the second you print the `char` itself from the `System.out.println` call

Comment: The members of [print/println/printf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println()) function families all return void!

Answer (score -1):

Read something about "Java Autoboxing and Unboxing"